# How to transform JavaScript object values into array

Tags: javascript, json

I need to write a function to transform an object like this:

```
const foodList = {fruit: {apples: true, pears: false, berries: true}, dairy: {milk: true, cheese: false}, vegetables: {}}
console.log(foodList)
```

into this:

```
const result = {fruit: ['apples', 'berries'], dairy: ['milk']}
console.log(result)
```

I'm trying to convert the nested values to an array where the food key equals true.

Comment: From where the property `deposits` come from, should not be `dairy`? Also, there is no `JSON` object, that is just a javascript object. A `JSON` is a string notation for an object.

Comment: How many layers nested do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. Use `reduce` to loop and summarize the array. Use `Object.keys` and `filter` to get the keys with true value.

```js
const foodList = {"fruit":{"apples":true,"pears":false,"berries":true},"dairy":{"milk":true,"cheese":false},"vegetables":{}}

const result = Object.entries(foodList).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
  let t = Object.keys(v);
  if (t.length) c[k] = t.filter(o => v[o]);
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to get the desired output is to use two nested `for` loops to traverse the outer and the inner keys while generating the resulting object. This way, you can also avoid to generate a `property` on the resulting `object` if all the elements inside a category have the `false` value.

```js
const foodList = {
  fruit: {apples: true, pears: false, berries: true},
  dairy: {milk: true, cheese: false},
  vegetables: {},
  food: {hamburger: false, spaghetti: false}
};

let res = {};

for (const category in foodList)
{
    for (const item in foodList[category])
    {
        if (foodList[category][item])
        {
            res[category] = res[category] || [];
            res[category].push(item);
        }
    }
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```